# Rebind a GridView Datasource after editing a Textbox in the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a DataGrid with a datasource on page load, but when I make changes to the Textboxes within the datagrid, I don't know how to get those new textbox.text.

I don't what to change the new datasource to??

So My question is how Do I update the datasource and save my new edited TextBox.Text field??...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }

    }

    protected void BindData()
    {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        currentCustomer = dao.SelectAll().First(x => x.CustomerID == 3) as Customer;

        //Assigning SQL Datasource to Gridview
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, MiddleIntial, LastName, DateOfBirth, TaxID, GenderId FROM Customer " +
            "WHERE CustomerID = " + 3;
        ClientGridView.DataBind();
    }

     protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set a new datasource here??

        string firstName = string.Empty;
        string middileInitial = string.Empty;
        string lastname = string.Empty;
        string date = string.Empty;
        DateTime dateOfBirth;
        string taxId = string.Empty;
        string strGender = string.Empty;
        int genderId = 0;


        foreach (GridViewRow r in ClientGridView.Rows)
        {
            firstName = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
            middileInitial = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtMiddleInitial")).Text;
            lastname = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
            date = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtDateOfBirth")).Text;
            taxId = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtTaxID")).Text;
            strGender = ((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtGenderID")).Text;
        }

    }
```

I have been searching for hours and found nothing really relating to my situation. I also feel like there should be a much better way then to implement all the event handlers for _RowEditing and _RowUpdating and I have tried these but none of their event handlers fired anyway....

EDIT: Heres  my GridView XAML

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ClientGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" OnRowEditing="ClientGridView_RowEditing" 
            Width="650px" PageSize="20" CssClass="gridView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBound="ClientGridView_DataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' CssClass="txtStyle"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Middle Initial" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="txtMiddleInitial" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleIntial") %>' CssClass="txtStyle" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="txtLastName" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' CssClass="txtStyle" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of birth" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateOfBirth" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth") %>' CssClass="txtStyle" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="txtTaxID" Text='<%# Bind("TaxID") %>' CssClass="txtStyle" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGenderID" Text='<%# Bind("GenderId") %>' CssClass="txtStyle" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

and the SQLDataSource

```
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
            ConnectionString=myconnectionString;User Id=userID;Password=pass; Persist Security Info=false;" />
```

Comment: Can you post markup for `SqlDataSource1` also? You should have `UpdateCommand` for `SqlDataSource1`.

Comment: Ok, i posted the markup. and I tried running the updateCommand and checking what e was bringing, and it was always bringing my original datasource items, never the newly updated ones.

Comment: You need to add UpdateCommand and UpdateParameters. I would recommend going through this tutorial: [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data with the SqlDataSource](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs).

Comment: I literally looked for like 5 hours yesterday searching for something...and this looks very very promising. Thank you very much for that link!