# How to update GridView from TextBox in ItemTemplate with List DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm stuck and have no idea what to do, can you help me please?

I have this grid in page markup

```
<asp:GridView  ID="gridEmployees" runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="<%# AllowSorting %>"
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdView_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnSorting="gridEmployees_Sorting" 
    OnRowEditing="gridEmployees_RowEditing"
    OnRowUpdating="gridEmployees_RowUpdating"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gridEmployees_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowUpdated="gridEmployees_RowUpdated"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full name" SortExpression="FullName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbSalary" Width="200px" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary" SortExpression="Salary">
            <%--http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET--%>
            <ItemTemplate >
                <div >
                    <asp:TextBox Width="100px" OnTextChanged="tbSalary_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" style="text-align: right" TextMode="SingleLine" runat="server" ID="tbSalary" Text='<%# Bind("Salary", "{0:c0}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want two columns - label (name) and textBox (salary). When user edits TextBox - data have to be updated automatically.

My CodeBehind looks like:

```
    private static readonly DbManager DbManager = new DbManager();

    private int selectedJobId = 1; // TODO:

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlJobs.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlJobs.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlJobs.DataSource = DbManager.GetJobs();
            ddlJobs.SelectedValue = selectedJobId.ToString();
            ddlJobs.DataBind();

            ddlJobs.DataBound += (o, args) =>
                {
                    selectedJobId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlJobs.SelectedValue);
                    FillTable();
                };
        }
        else
        {
            selectedJobId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlJobs.SelectedValue);
        }
        Page.DataBind();
    }

    protected void FillTable()
    {
        gridEmployees.DataSource = GetEmployees(); // List<Employees>
        gridEmployees.DataBind();
    }
```

I thought that row will raise Updated event when I update TextBox, but, unfortunately, it doesnt, probaly it's 'cause grid is not in editMode. So, I just made workaround - if TB edited - raise event and process it.

Well, now page is reloading with IsPostback = false, but no event is raised, not WebGrid's not TB's.

I've found some clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836507/rebind-a-gridview-datasource-after-editing-a-textbox-in-the-itemtemplate), but my source is not SqlDataSource. What's wrong with my code, source? How to update row when TB changed in my case.

Comment: Where is the event "tbSalary_TextChanged" ??

Comment: @SirajMansour

I have all event handlers inside of code-behind, they are empty just for breakpoints. 

Well, look, now property is:
OnTextChanged="tbSalary_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"

Handler is
        protected void tbSalary_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

But no exception occured. Just Page_Load with PostBack == false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through this artical .You will be able to fire textchange event from textbox inside the gridview
[http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663684/Fire-TextBox-TextChanged-Event-from-GridView][1]